# Altering my datetime regular expression to make entering seconds optional

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression, for use in a javascript function, to test datetimes.

I'm wanting to allow dates in the following formats only:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss
YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm
```

This is as far as I've managed to get so far:

```
/^(19[0-9]{2}|2[0-9]{3})-(0[1-9]|1[012])-([123]0|[012][1-9]|31)[ \/T\/t]([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$/
```

It does what I want except requires hours, minutes and seconds rather than hours and minutes with seconds optional.

Thanks for your help!

I've written a small jsFiddle with some test data to make your lives easier. Just update the pattern variable and run it and the table should match up.

http://jsfiddle.net/smMJC/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I updated this answer to change (...) to (?:...) so your capturing won't be messed up.

Try this:

```
/^(19[0-9]{2}|2[0-9]{3})-(0[1-9]|1[012])-([123]0|[012][1-9]|31)[ \/T\/t]([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])(?::([0-5][0-9]))?$/
```

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/smMJC/5/

What I did was changing

```
:([0-5][0-9])
```

to:

```
(?::([0-5][0-9]))?
```

which means making that part optional. (The double colon is intentional because it is a `(?: ... )?` non capturing group outside and a literal ":" inside.

Also, you may want to change:

```
[ \/T\/t]
```

to:

```
[ Tt]
```

unless you really want to match strings like:

```
2013-01-01/15:30:30
```

with a slash instead of T - compare those two demos:

- http://jsfiddle.net/smMJC/3/
- http://jsfiddle.net/smMJC/4/

Comment: Thanks for your help and the explanation. I've never used regular expression before so I've been struggling. I've taken your advice and changed [ \/T\/t] as well! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Change

- `[0-9]` to `\d`
- simplify time indicator to `[ t]` and add case insensitive modifier `/.../i`
- seconds `:([0-5]\d)` to optional `(?::([0-5]\d))?`

Regex:

```
/^(19|2\d)\d\d-(0[1-9]|1[012])-([123]0|[012][1-9]|31)[ t]([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)(?::([0-5]\d))?$/i
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smMJC/9/)

If you don't need to capture the individual parts of your datetime string

- remove the parenthesis `()` where possible
- replace parenthesis `()` by non-capturing `(?:...)` where needed

Regex:

```
/^(?:19|2\d)\d\d-(?:0[1-9]|1[012])-(?:[123]0|[012][1-9]|31)[ t](?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d(?::[0-5]\d)?$/i
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smMJC/8/)

Comment: Thanks for your help with simplifying my expression I'm much obliged. I'll make the changes you suggested.